# Problem with plotting regression line from spline in ggplot2

Tags: r, scatter-plot, spline

I have a dataset where I have bacterial carriage by age group. I used the bs spline function to model bacterial carriage by age.

```
fit2 <- lm(percentage ~ bs(Age_midpoint, knots = c(0.177, 1, 1.460, 2.585, 5, 8.75, 37.45)), data = Complete_data)
fit2
age <-range(Complete_data$Age_midpoint)
Age_grid <- seq(from=min(age), to = max(age))
pred2 <-predict(fit2, newdata = list(Age_midpoint = Age_grid), se = T)
se_bands = with(pred2, cbind("upper" = fit+2*se.fit, "lower" = fit-2*se.fit))
```

I now want to plot the line that describes fit2 in the following plot:

```
Fig1 <- ggplot(Complete_data, aes(x= Age_midpoint, y = percentage)) + geom_point(shape=1, aes( size = denominator)) + xlab("Average age") + ylab("Pneumococcal Carriage") + theme_light()
```

I am able to plot the line by itself using this:`

```
ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x = Age_midpoint.grid, y=pred2$fit), color = "red") + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = Age_midpoint.grid, ymin=se_bands[, "lower"], ymax = se_bands[, "upper"]), alpha = 0.3) + xlim(age)
```

But when I try to plot the line in the scatterplot I get a warning

```
 Fig1 + geom_line(aes(x = Age_midpoint.grid, y=pred2$fit), color = "red") + 
 geom_ribbon(aes(x = Age_midpoint.grid, ymin=se_bands[, "lower"], ymax = se_bands[, "upper"]), alpha = 0.3) + xlim(age)


 Error in geom_line(aes(x = Age_midpoint.grid, y = pred2$fit), color = "red") : 
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (403)
✖ Fix the following mappings: `x` and `y`
```

How can I plot the line in my scatterplot?

I looked online for solution, but I only found information about histograms.

Comment: You would make life easier for yourself if you put all the components of your regression line into a data frame and pass this data frame to the `data` parameter of your line and ribbon. You could even save yourself all the trouble of pre-calculating the regression line and using `geom_smooth` instead. If you include a reproducible example of data in your question we could show you how.

Comment: Thank you. Here is an example of the data:                                                                            
    Age_midpoint <- c(2.5, 2.5, 2.7, 38.1, 9.5, 1.0, 2.5)
    denominator <- c(370, 148, 1006, 267, 417, 387, 372)
    percentage <- c(82.2, 77.0, 55.1, 55.5, 37.4, 75.2, 38.4)